# Simple Form: Non object related attribute. How to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have a simple form that looks like this:

```
 <%= simple_form_for @study,:url => studies_path, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :category, :collection => @categories, :label => "Category", :selected => @categories.first %>
  <%= f.button :submit, t('add_form'),:class => 'btn-primary' %>
```

I want to add a new field in that form that will be merely visual sugar. It will be a helper to dynamically change the :category field.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `text_field_tag` or whichever other `_tag` helper to generate a form element without attaching it to any specific attribute of the model:

```
<%= simple_form_for @study,:url => studies_path, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :category, :collection => @categories, :label => "Category", :selected => @categories.first %>
  <%= text_field_tag :blah %>
  <%= f.button :submit, t('add_form'),:class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I can do that, but then I lose the html structure and styling that simple form gives. Do you suggest trying to mock what simple form automatically generates when doing f.input?